# SearchKit: rewrite value dependent on value in a separate field

Tags: smarty, searchkit

I am using SearchKit to build a professional membership register in Civi 5.58.1.
I want to show the value in a transformed field from the search (showing professional registration details), only if the field "Registration Status" does not have the value "Retired".
I have tried using the following Smarty code in Rewrite, which does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
{capture assign=RegStatus}{[Membership_Contact_contact_id_01.Details_ccc.Registration_status:label]}{/capture}
{capture assign=RegDetails}{[CONCAT_WS_Membership_Contact_contact_id_01_Details_ccc_Practise_Licensing_Authority_Membership_Contact_contact_id_01_Details_ccc_Practise_license_number]}{/capture}
{If $RegStatus eq 'Retired'}
{$null}
{else}{$RegDetails}
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi.Not sure how the actual table display is structed but this for example works to show some custom contact information for a member with 'new' status on dmaster - {if  '[Contact_Membership_contact_id_01.status_id:label]'  eq 'New'}[constituent_information.Most_Important_Issue:label]{else}{/if}

Comment: Thank you Rebecca - I can see it was a syntax problem - you solved it! Much appreciated